# Unable to retrieve cards with listSources or listCards method

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions, stripe-payments

Having successfully added a card to the customer (create with Stripe.js createSource, attach with stripe-node createSource), I'm unable to access the card(s) with listCards or listSources. I can however access them using *paymentMethods.list*.

**Card attached using:**

```js
// server
const attachSource = async (customerId: string, source: string) =>
   await stripe.customers.createSource(customerId, { source });
```

**List the card(s):**

```js
// server
export const listCards = async (customerId: string, limit?: number) =>
    await stripe.customers.listCards(customerId, { limit });
```

**The proof:**
[image]

My Stripe dashboard doesn't show a Sources section; the cards added via the top method appear in the Cards section.

Context: node server with callable Firebase cloud functions speaking to stripe v3 node client.

Comment: You should add all your code for us to be able to help you.

Comment: Can you provide more context, do you see the cards/sources attached to the customer in your stripe dashboard. What's the code you're using to add the source then list cards server-side? https://stripe.com/docs/api/cards/list server-side